# Firefox : 2 specific settings can't be modified into about:config

Tags: firefox

I use Firefox 37.0.1, which is currently up to date.

I installed a [new plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tabs-closebutton-restored/) into Firefox, then uninstalled it.
I since have a problem with tabs. So I opened about:config and gone to "browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent" to correct the problem.

- as expected, this setting is in bold, meaning it is not at the default value (default=true, current value=false)
- a backup of this setting named "browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent.backup" is created (with the previous and default value: true)
- I can't switch the setting to true. No message, no error, just nothing when I double-click on it, or with the right-click menu
- the setting is not in italic, and the status column doesn't display "locked"
- I searched for a [locking file](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Locking_preferences), and found nothing
- I close Firefox, edit prefs.js to remove the "browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent" line. Once Firefox is restarted, the line come back (to the wrong value: false)
- I have the same behaviour into another existing user account, as well as into a new user account. So this is probably something global
- I grepped into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox" and found no occurence of "browser.tabs"
- if I create "user.js" into my Firefox user profile directory, with a line setting "browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent" to true, it is still false into about:config
- I [refreshed Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings). Same problem

Where can I search to find the origin of this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. When I disable the plugin Tree Style Tab the setting is settable again. Re-enabling the plugin causes the unsettable broser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent. I guess hijacking the setting is fine but still the middle click on links opens new tabs at end of tree. Same issue as https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1042680 I guess.